# My multithread functions are doing what they are supposed to however, still receiving an error in the terminal

Tags: python, multithreading, function, variables, nameerror

Playing around with multithreading, whereby I create x amount of files and write the Fibonacci number within each file. The output is as expected- 7 files and a folder with each file containing the Fibonacci number.

However, I get a name error in the terminal and I don't understand why considering it's reading the variable and parsing it through.

```
def create_folder():
        path="C:\\Users\\HansPeterJonasHogh-J\\dev\\docs\\pyhtonexercise\\async_multi"
        os.chdir(path)
        fib_folder= 'fibFolder-01'
        os.makedirs(fib_folder)

def generate_array(fib_position):
    fibarray=[1,] 
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 1
    current_index = 1
    fibnum=0
    while current_index < fib_position:
            fibnum = (num1+num2)
            num1 = num2
            num2 = fibnum
            current_index = (current_index+1)
            fibarray.append(int(fibnum))
    return(fibarray)

def write_file(fibarray):
    for X in range(1, len(fibarray) +1):
        with open(f"fib-number-{X}.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(str(fibarray[:X]))
            file.close()

if __name__== "__main__":
    fib_position = 7


# multiprocessing
st = time.time()

p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_array, args=(fib_position, ))


create_folder()
p2.start()

#p1.join()
#p2.join()

st = time.time()
en = time.time()
print("time taken = ", en-st)
```

here is the error:

```
    J\dev\docs\pyhtonexercise\async_multi\three_programs.py", line 37, in <module>
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_array, args=(fib_position, ))
    NameError: name 'fib_position' is not defined
```

Comment: I believe the lines below `# multiprocessing` should be indented, so that they're part of your `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement. Furthermore, when using `with open()... as f` you don't need to close the file explicitly.

Comment: processes and threads are not the same thing

Comment: you use multiprocessing, not multithreading. And multiprocessing run code inside `if __name__== "__main__":` only in main process - so they create `fib_position = 7` only in main process. But you have `p2 = multiprocessing.Process()` outside `if __name__== "__main__":`` so they can be executed in other processes (which don't run `fib_position = 7`). Indentations are very important in Python - and they change everything in this code.